# Java applet not able to find resource image with ImageIcon unless entire path is used

Tags: java, eclipse, image, applet

I've placed the image TestIcon.png in the src folder of a Java applet (the directory is C:\Users\User\workspace\applettest2\src\TestIcon.png). Everything I've read says that I should be able to use the image simply by referencing "TestIcon.png". Example:

```
ImageIcon xIcon = new ImageIcon("TestIcon.png");
```

Howerver, running the applet in Eclipse with this code doesn't work; the image is not displayed. If I type out the image's entire path:

```
ImageIcon xIcon = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\User\\workspace\\applettest2\\src\\TestIcon.png");
```

then the applet displays the image properly. Isn't the default path for resources supposed to be in the "src" folder? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running it inside the Applet then try with [Applet#getCodeBase()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/applet/Applet.html#getCodeBase()) and [Applet#getDocumentBase](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/applet/Applet.html#getDocumentBase())

```
Image image = getImage(getDocumentBase(), "TestIcon.png");
```

Find more samples [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7440339/how-can-i-display-an-image-in-the-applet) and [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7708612/display-image-and-play-audio-clip-in-applet)